# Rails 4 Combining a Date_field and Time_field into single datetime attribute on active record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, forms, form-helpers

*I am trying to combine a date_field and a time_field and not date_select and time_select as I do not want 5 separate input fields*

I have a school course model with a start_date attribute. This is the form as near as I would like have it.

```
<%= form_for @school_course do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :start_date %>
  <%= f.date_field :start_date %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

To pass both of these fields through to the model I am wondering do I have to pass them as an array and the manually stitch them into a single datetime object? Or is there a more rails way to combine a date and time input field?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the form helper `datetime_field`? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Yes. It doesn't have a nice dropdown. Or at least it doesn't when I look at it in chrome

Comment: If you're only concerned about Chrome, you could use a [`datetime_local_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-datetime_local_field) which should give you a nice input with a datepicker (for now). IE/Firefox/Safari won't though, and I think that's because `datetime` and `datetime-local` have been removed from the HTML5 spec. Otherwise the "Rails way" is to use a `datetime_select` which uses some voodoo behind the scenes to combine the fields. You already said you don't want to do that, so manually stitching is probably your only remaining option.

Comment: Or, of course, you could use some [third-party Javascript datetime picker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/), if you're not set on the native browser ones.